# Plots do not appear in plot pane of updated version of RStudio

Tags: plot

None of my plots are appearing in my plot pane or anywhere else. I've tried dev.off but it doesn't work and i've doubled checked that plots is checked off in global options. Help please!

> dev.off()
>   Error in dev.off() : cannot shut down device 1 (the null device)
>
> sessionInfo()
>   R version 3.2.5 (2016-04-14)
>   Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
>   Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252

attached base packages:
[1] splines   stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
 [1] tsne_0.1-3         RColorBrewer_1.1-2 mgcv_1.8-17        nlme_3.1-131       SpadeR_0.1.1
 [6] psych_1.7.3.21     fpc_2.1-10         clue_0.3-53        FD_1.0-12          geometry_0.3-6
[11] magic_1.5-6        abind_1.4-5        ape_4.1            ade4_1.7-6         stringr_1.2.0
[16] readxl_0.1.1       DT_0.2             rerddap_0.3.4      vegan_2.4-3        lattice_0.20-35
[21] permute_0.9-4      scales_0.4.1       leaflet_1.1.0      raster_2.5-8       sp_1.2-4
[26] lubridate_1.6.0    dplyr_0.5.0        purrr_0.2.2        readr_1.1.0        tidyr_0.6.1
[31] tibble_1.3.0       ggplot2_2.2.1      tidyverse_1.1.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] httr_1.2.1        jsonlite_1.4      modelr_0.1.0      shiny_1.0.2       assertthat_0.2.0 
 [6] stats4_3.2.5      robustbase_0.92-7 digest_0.6.12     rvest_0.3.2       colorspace_1.3-2 
[11] htmltools_0.3.5   httpuv_1.3.3      Matrix_1.2-8      plyr_1.8.4        broom_0.4.2
[16] haven_1.0.0       mvtnorm_1.0-6     xtable_1.8-2      nnet_7.3-12       lazyeval_0.2.0
[21] mnormt_1.5-5      magrittr_1.5      mime_0.5          mclust_5.2.3      ncdf4_1.16
[26] MASS_7.3-45       class_7.3-14      forcats_0.2.0     xml2_1.1.1        foreign_0.8-67
[31] tools_3.2.5       data.table_1.10.4 hms_0.3           trimcluster_0.1-2 kernlab_0.9-25
[36] munsell_0.4.3     cluster_2.0.6     grid_3.2.5        htmlwidgets_0.8   crosstalk_1.0.0
[41] labeling_0.3      gtable_0.2.0      flexmix_2.3-13    DBI_0.6-1         reshape2_1.4.2
[46] R6_2.2.0          prabclus_2.2-6    knitr_1.15.1      modeltools_0.2-21 stringi_1.1.5
[51] parallel_3.2.5    Rcpp_0.12.10      DEoptimR_1.0-8    diptest_0.75-7

Comment: Did you try  any plot on RGui instead of RStudio?

Comment: I updated all my packages and then restarted my computer and r session.

Comment: It is now working. Thank you for the advice